# How to calculate Window width and center of DICOM image from VOILut tag

Tags: c#, .net, dicom

in a dicom image file WW and WC/WL are not included but VOI Lut tag is present and i want to calculate WW and WL from it

Comment: What you have tried so far ?
Please add some code sample along with question

Answer (score 2):

A VOI LUT is typically used for non-linear transformations of the pixel data, i.e. for transformations which can *not* be expressed by specifying WL/WW. For that reason, it is impossible to calculate WL/WW from VOI LUT.

[EDIT]: To be even more clear:

WL/WW is limited to **linear** transformations of the grayscales. So the difference between the mapped value of x and (x+1) is equal to the difference of the mapped value of y and (y+1).

This does not count for the VOI LUT module which was introduced to allow for **non-linear** transformations of the grayscales. That is, no assumptions can be taken about the correllation of mapped values (x, x+1), (y, y+1). VOI LUT can be used to define **any weird curve** for mapping gray values.

"any weird curve" can obviously not be approximated by a strictly linear function. For that reason, it is possible to express WL/WW by VOI LUT but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for replying, But I want to know that how we can calculate WL/WL from VOI LUT

Comment: you are welcome....and I am telling you that this (=calculating WW/WL from VOI LUT) is only going to work in very exceptional cases.WW/WC is LINEAR while VOI LUT is usually NON-LINEAR.